# Restricting page access based on retrieved object values

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebasesimplelogin, nosql

So let's say I have the following user property and I want to restrict access to a page. This is in my Firebase noSQL database but I think this could pertain to obtaining data from anywhere.

```
{
    "users": {
      "simplelogin:1": {
         "properties": { "admin_user": true }
      }
    }
}
```

So in my javascript I have the following:

```
var user_properties = new Firebase("https://<MY-URL>.com/users/"+auth.uid+"/properties");
user_properties.once("value", function(properties) {
    if(properties.val().admin_user == false)
        window.location.replace("/");
});
```

So, on the page load of the "admin page", I load this javascript. And if they aren't an admin, the page is supposed to redirect.

However, I'm having the problem where the admin page will load for a second while it gathers the data and then redirect.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can make the page redirect before the page even loads?

Comment: *Nothing* you do client-side will adequately prevent users from seeing that page. Instead, I suggest you do the check server-side, and then either serve the page or serve a redirect.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. So should I save my authentication token in cookies when a user logs in to be able to check this information server-side? Or is there a more appropriate way? @T.J.Crowder

Comment: It depends a lot on how your users are authenticated. If you're doing some kind of integrated authentication, presumably you won't need a cookie or similar. If not and you're relying on sessions, you'll either need a cookie or a value that gets resubmitted every time to identify the session. The value you use in that should ideally identify the session but nothing else about the user, and be encrypted (with salt), and ideally tied to a specific IP (as IPs rarely change during a user session). So when you see the page send it in, you find the session, and identify the user from it.

Comment: As T.J. already says: you cannot prevent a user from reaching a page by writing code on the client. What you can (and should do) is remove links to the admin page for users that are not administrators. But that is just a UX thing, the user can still type the URL of the admin page directly into the browser and reach it that way. So: yes, you should redirect them back if they reach the admin page and are not administrators, but you should not pretend that this is security.

Comment: You should wonder if you really need to secure the admin page, or if you really only care about the data-modification actions users can perform from there. Since you're using Firebase, it's quite common that the only thing you really need to secure is the data. And that is fortunately something that Firebase has a pretty good security language for, which (non-coincidentally) is applied on the server.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I see where you are coming from Frank, the security behind doing what users should and shouldn't be able to do works very well. I just don't like the notion of people being able to see pages they shouldn't even if they technically don't even know they exist.

Comment: I understand. So I normally hide the links to those page and make the page itself redirect back to safety. But I really wouldn't care about them temporarily seeing that page, as long as they can't modify the data. If such an approach is not good enough for your application, you'll need a server-side solution that redirects the users away from your admin page.

Comment: It's good enough to start. Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen

Answer (score 1):

[Security rules in Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/) can prevent the page from data from being viewed without permission. Then you simply need a client-side solution to redirect the page. The simple answer here is to use `resolve` in your routes.

You can find a complete implementation of this approach in the [angularFire-seed project](https://github.com/firebase/angularFire-seed). Here's the [relevant code](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire-seed/blob/master/app/js/routes.js):

```
"use strict";

angular.module('myApp.routes', ['ngRoute', 'simpleLogin'])

  .constant('ROUTES', {
    '/home': {
      templateUrl: 'partials/home.html',
      controller: 'HomeCtrl',
      resolve: {
        // forces the page to wait for this promise to resolve before controller is loaded
        // the controller can then inject `user` as a dependency. This could also be done
        // in the controller, but this makes things cleaner (controller doesn't need to worry
        // about auth status or timing of displaying its UI components)
        user: ['simpleLogin', function(simpleLogin) {
          return simpleLogin.getUser();
        }]
      }
    },
    '/chat': {
      templateUrl: 'partials/chat.html',
      controller: 'ChatCtrl'
    },
    '/login': {
      templateUrl: 'partials/login.html',
      controller: 'LoginCtrl'
    },
    '/account': {
      templateUrl: 'partials/account.html',
      controller: 'AccountCtrl',
      // require user to be logged in to view this route
      // the whenAuthenticated method below will resolve the current user
      // before this controller loads and redirect if necessary
      authRequired: true
    }
  })

  /**
   * Adds a special `whenAuthenticated` method onto $routeProvider. This special method,
   * when called, invokes the requireUser() service (see simpleLogin.js).
   *
   * The promise either resolves to the authenticated user object and makes it available to
   * dependency injection (see AuthCtrl), or rejects the promise if user is not logged in,
   * forcing a redirect to the /login page
   */
  .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    // credits for this idea: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/angular/dPr9BpIZID0/MgWVluo_Tg8J
    // unfortunately, a decorator cannot be use here because they are not applied until after
    // the .config calls resolve, so they can't be used during route configuration, so we have
    // to hack it directly onto the $routeProvider object
    $routeProvider.whenAuthenticated = function(path, route) {
      route.resolve = route.resolve || {};
      route.resolve.user = ['requireUser', function(requireUser) {
        return requireUser();
      }];
      $routeProvider.when(path, route);
    }
  }])

  // configure views; the authRequired parameter is used for specifying pages
  // which should only be available while logged in
  .config(['$routeProvider', 'ROUTES', function($routeProvider, ROUTES) {
    angular.forEach(ROUTES, function(route, path) {
      if( route.authRequired ) {
        // adds a {resolve: user: {...}} promise which is rejected if
        // the user is not authenticated or fulfills with the user object
        // on success (the user object is then available to dependency injection)
        $routeProvider.whenAuthenticated(path, route);
      }
      else {
        // all other routes are added normally
        $routeProvider.when(path, route);
      }
    });
    // routes which are not in our map are redirected to /home
    $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/home'});
  }])

  /**
   * Apply some route security. Any route's resolve method can reject the promise with
   * { authRequired: true } to force a redirect. This method enforces that and also watches
   * for changes in auth status which might require us to navigate away from a path
   * that we can no longer view.
   */
  .run(['$rootScope', '$location', 'simpleLogin', 'ROUTES', 'loginRedirectPath',
    function($rootScope, $location, simpleLogin, ROUTES, loginRedirectPath) {
      // watch for login status changes and redirect if appropriate
      simpleLogin.watch(check, $rootScope);

      // some of our routes may reject resolve promises with the special {authRequired: true} error
      // this redirects to the login page whenever that is encountered
      $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeError", function(e, next, prev, err) {
        if( angular.isObject(err) && err.authRequired ) {
          $location.path(loginRedirectPath);
        }
      });

      function check(user) {
        if( !user && authRequired($location.path()) ) {
          $location.path(loginRedirectPath);
        }
      }

      function authRequired(path) {
        return ROUTES.hasOwnProperty(path) && ROUTES[path].authRequired;
      }
    }
  ]);
```